# Sketch the region enclosed by $y=|x|$, $y=x^2-4$. Decide whether to integrate WRT x or y, then find the area of the region

Tags: calculus

One of those wonderful problems that was never discussed in class - any help would be much appreciated - I've been going at this darn thing all night :/

Comment: If you've been working at it that long, surely you have some thoughts you can share with us :)

Comment: I've tried to integrate (x-(x^2-4) from -4,4, didn't work. Tried the same integral from 0,4 with a 2 out in front of the integrand because of the symmetry, didn't work. I've basically tried every method we went over and lecture and none of them work. I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong since we never discussed anything with absolute value in this section (and there's nothing in my textbook either). I've also tried Google and Youtube to find ANYTHING to deal with |X|, but to no avail.

Comment: You should start by drawing a picture, if you haven't already. The region of integration will extend between the two values of $x$ where $|x|$ and $x^2-4$ intersect. Note by the way that $|x|$ is just two lines: $y=-x$ if $x<0$ and $y=x$ if $x\ge 0$. You should be able to put all of this together into an integral.

Comment: And, BTW, you are right to try to exploit the fact that the region is symmetric. And a comment I just read in another post: "absolute values are a pain...you should always (well, ALMOST always) simplify to get rid of them". See my previous comment for a hint as to how to do that.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=region+enclosed+by+%7Cx%7C+and+x%5E2-4 . Check this out, it should give you a better grasp on the big picture. Might come out as a bit of a spoiler regarding the final answer, but I do believe that a proper plot like this one might enlighten you

Answer (score 1):

The region is symmetric with respect to the y-axis, so we deal with the half on the positive x part of the plane, and then the result will have to be multiplied by 2.

$\text{Let us call } f(x)=x \text{ and } g(x)=x^2-4$,

$\text{if you draw their graphs for }x>0\text{ you can notice that the total sum is composed}$

$\text{by three different regions:}$

$\ A_1= \int_{0}^{2}\ x dx $

$\ A_2= |\int_{0}^{2}\ (x^2-4)dx|= -\int_{0}^{2}\ (x^2-4)dx$

$\ A_3= \int_{2}^{(1+\sqrt17)\over2}\ xdx -\int_{2}^{(1+\sqrt17)\over2}\ (x^2-4)dx  $

$\text{note that for }\ x=(1+\sqrt17)/2 \text{ we have the point of intersection.}$

$\text {So the total sum will be:}$

$\ I=A_1+A_2+A_3=\int_{0}^{(1+\sqrt17)/2}\ (x-x^2+4)dx=[(x^2/2)-(x^3/3)+(4x)|_{0}^{(1+\sqrt17)/2}= $

$\ =(\frac{1+\sqrt17}{24})(3(1+\sqrt17)-(1+\sqrt17)^2+48)≈7.92$

$\text  {therefore the total area will be: }\ ≈ 2(7.92)=15.8$

$\text{So your intuition was right, in fact}\ I= 2\int_{0}^{(1+\sqrt17)\over2}\ [f(x)-g(x)]dx $

$\text{and not between 4 and -4.}$

$\text{I hope this was helpful.}$